# WPF ListView data binding with Image dopesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding

I have this code, which is supposed to display images of the product in a listview:

```
namespace BoeshCRM
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for NewBill.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class NewBill : Page
    {
        ObservableCollection<ProdImg> Inventory 
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<ProdImg>)GetValue(InventoryProperty); }
            set { SetValue(InventoryProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty InventoryProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Inventory", typeof(ObservableCollection<ProdImg>), typeof(MainWindow), null);

        public NewBill()
        {          
            InitializeComponent();
            Inventory = new ObservableCollection<ProdImg>(); 
            Inventory.Add(new ProdImg(Product.LoadProduct(13L)));

        }
    }
}
```

This is the actual XML for the Page

```
<Page x:Class="BoeshCRM.NewBill"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
    Title="NewBill">

    <Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="lstItems" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" MinWidth="50" MinHeight="50" ItemsSource="{Binding Inventory}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding imgFi}"  />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

And this is the code for the helper classes, and the ProdImg struct.

```
namespace BoeshCRM
{

    struct ProdImg
    {
        public Product p;
        public FileInfo imgFi;

        public ProdImg(Product _p)
        {
            p = _p;
            imgFi = new FileInfo("C:/" + p.id.ToString() + ".jpg");
        }

    }
}
```

However no Image is displayed. Any idea why?
The LoadProduct method is not the problem, it works just fine.

Comment: check the output window for actual error. so far a best guess would be that `FileInfo` is not convertible to `ImageSource`

Answer (score 0):

Create property in ProdImg and bind to its FullName

```
public class ProdImg
{
    public Product p;
    public FileInfo imgFi;

    public ProdImg(Product _p)
    {
        p = _p;
        imgFi = new FileInfo("C:/" + p.id.ToString() + ".jpg");
    }

    public FileInfo ImgFi
    {
        get { return imgFi ; }
        set {imgFi = value; }
     }

}

<Image Source="{Binding ImgFi.FullName}"  />
```